# Google Colab does not show output during cell execution

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have been working on an image classifying algorithm and due to insufficient memory on a local machine, had to move to Colab. There is a cell which is responsible for training and inside the training function there are print statements which are supposed to keep me informed on how the process goes - these are never giving me the output during the cell's execution. What is more interesting, I have put the usual "hello" print statement at the very beginning of the cell and it is not appearing as well - I have waited hours for it to show up, no result. I tried the same code at the Microsoft Azure ML environment and it works perfectly fine (output is present). What might be the cause of such an issue? Image attached below. Thanks!

[image: 1]

Comment: Try to avoid posting code screenshots instead of actual code

Comment: okay, sorry, my first post here